# drop-down not getting selected with the selected value in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using drop-down in ng-repeat in angular js,

and my HTML code is

```
<select class="form-control"  ng-model="l.Language" ng-change="languageChange($index, l.Language)" ng-options="L.ID as L.LanguageDDL for L in LanguageDDLList track by L.ID" required></select>
```

And my controller is

```
 function getLanguagesFromLookup() {
    LanguagesService.getLanguagesfromLookup($scope.userId).success(function (data) {
        var languagesListfromLookup = data.customtableitem[0]["Lookup"];
        $scope.LanguageDDLList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < languagesListfromLookup.length; i++) {
            var item = {
                ID: languagesListfromLookup[i].ItemID,
                LanguageDDL: languagesListfromLookup[i].Skill
            }
            $scope.LanguageDDLList.push(item);
        }
    }).error(function (data) {
        $log.info("Error occured while getting Languages Dropdown.")
    });
}
```

And to get the default value

```
$scope.Language =  $scope.LanguageDDLList[0].ID
```

The problem i am facing here is I am getting the value i.e 1 in the model, but in the drop-down is not getting selected with the option that is having the Value as 1.

Can any one please suggest what would be the problem [Attached reference Image Please click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMSZK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your ngModel to l.Language but set $scope.Language. That's why your dropdown is not selected.

```
<select class="form-control"  ng-model="l.Language" ng-change="languageChange($index, l.Language)" ng-options="L.ID as L.LanguageDDL for L in LanguageDDLList track by L.ID" required></select>
```

Example plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XGfLAjt2lhV8KCgxgchu?p=info)

UPDATE:
Extended plunk with a wrapping ng-repeat and removed track by L.ID because we are already selecting the ID.

Comment: That l is pointing to ng-repeate i.e ng-repeate="l in languages"

Comment: I updated the answer and plunk. Does this work for you now?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     $scope.Language =  parseInt($scope.LanguageDDLList[0].ID+"");
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Comment: I converted it to integer because option value for select is integer